# raw moments command in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics

In octave I can get raw moment of of any sample like this,

```
rm = moment(x,2,'r');
```

But there doesn't seem to be such option Matlab.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you read the [MATLAB docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/moment.html) on this subject?

Comment: Possibly missing the Statistics Toolbox?

Comment: only central moments. No raw moments.

Comment: Ah, I understand now... i don't know of any offhand, but I'll have a look. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a predefined function, but it's very easy. The `n`-th raw moment of the samples contained in vector `x` is

```
mean(x.^n)
```

If `x` is matrix and you want the raw moment of each colum:

```
mean(x.^n, 1)
```